# Creating the Proper JSON From APEX

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, json

Hi i am new to the requirement as i need to create the JSON from the APEX in the Below format:
JSON Format:

```
{
    "securiandocnumber": [
        "3970118"
        "3987556"
    ],
    "caseId": "123"
}
```

Below is the class  i have created requesting you to help me out to create the JSON:

```
 public class SFG_CasePostWebService {

    public SFG_CasePostWebService(){
    }
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void frameCaseWebService(){

        //Query out the data from Salesforce database.
        List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
        caseList=[Select id From Case];
        Case_Associated_Document__c[] caseAssoDoc = [SELECT Id, Document_Id__c FROM Case_Associated_Document__c WHERE Service_Request__r.Id = :caseList];

        //Formation of the JSON 
    } 
    public class CaseDetails {
        public String[] securianDocNumbers;
        public String caseId;

    }
  }
```

Forget to mention : Document_Id__c == securiandocnumber
                    caseId = Id(From Case)

Comment: Covered in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm

Comment: That's not even valid JSON. Can you copy/paste it so you don't bring type mistakes into the problem?

Comment: My Json should form like:{ "Securiandocnumber":[ "3970118" "3987556" ], "caseId":"123" }

Comment: What is securiandocnumber ?

Answer (score 1):

Few Things I add-in your code.

- You created a `CaseDetails` apex class which is correct, I add a constructor which is missing
- Create a `Map<String,List<String>` for to store caseId related to document.
- Loop through the Map and Add data into List of CaseDetails `List<CaseDetails>`
- After that, for serializing the list, I used `JSON.serialize`.

**So here are my final changes**

```
    public class SFG_CasePostWebService {

    public SFG_CasePostWebService(){
    }
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void frameCaseWebService(){

        //Query out the data from Salesforce database.
        List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
        caseList=[Select id From Case];
        Map<String,List<String>> m = new Map<String,List<String>>();
            for(Case_Associated_Document__c caseAssoDoc = [SELECT Id,Service_Request__r.Id, Document_Id__c FROM Case_Associated_Document__c WHERE Service_Request__r.Id = :caseList]){
                if(m.containsKey(caseAssoDoc.Service_Request__r.Id))
                    m.get(caseAssoDoc.Service_Request__r.Id).add(caseAssoDoc.Document_Id__c);
                else
                    m.put(caseAssoDoc.Service_Request__r.Id,new List<String>{caseAssoDoc.Document_Id__c});
            }
        List<CaseDetails> lst = new List<CaseDetails>();
        for( String obj : m.keySet() ){
            lst.add(new CaseDetails(obj,m.get(obj)));
        }
        //you will get the serialize JSON Data.
        System.debug('lst::'+JSON.serialize(lst));
    } 
    public class CaseDetails {
        public String caseId;
        public List<String> securianDocNumbers;

        CaseDetails(String caseId, List<String> securianDocNumbers){
            this.caseId = caseId;
            this.securianDocNumbers = securianDocNumbers;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks For Help : Sorry i forget to mention : as Document_Id__c == securiandocnumber caseId = Id(From Case)  ,, Req to help me out to form the Proper JSON For POST Method

Comment: @Abhijeet , Please see my updated Answer

Comment: Thanks For Help :)

Comment: Can you help me out i am not able to get using Map as u have used above in your Code.

Comment: Can You help Me out how you have used the Map here.

Comment: what the issue are you facing with a map.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your CaseDetails Class and the JSON String, It seems there is a comma missing in the JSON. It should be as below.

```
{
    "securiandocnumber": [
        "3970118",
        "3987556"
    ],
    "caseId": "123"
}
```

Now to create a JSON String you can use `serialize(objectToSerialize)` method from [JSON Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm). You have to instantiate the CaseDetails class fill it with all details then use `JSON.serialize` to get the JSON String.

```
CaseDetails cd = new CaseDetails();
//TBD - Fill all the fields in the CaseDetails Object
String jsonString = JSON.serialize(cd);
```